# How to get data from VerticaDB with Pyspark

Tags: database, apache-spark, pyspark, etl, vertica

I am trying to get data from VerticaDb with pyspark but I have error is called Class Not Found Exception.

Error: **Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o165.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.vertica.spark.datasource.VerticaSource.**

My code is here :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
from pyspark import sql

# Create the spark session
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Vertica Connector Pyspark Example") \
    .getOrCreate()
spark_context = spark.sparkContext
sql_context = sql.SQLContext(spark_context)


# The name of our connector for Spark to look up
format = "com.vertica.spark.datasource.VerticaSource"

# Set connector options based on our Docker setup
table = "*****"
db = "*****"
user = "********"
password = "********"
host = "******"
part = "1";
staging_fs_url="****"


#spark.read.format("com.vertica.spark.datasource.VerticaSource").options(opt).load()


readDf = spark.read.load(
 # Spark format
 format=format,
 # Connector specific options
 host=host,
 user=user,
 password=password,
 db=db,
 table=table)

# Print the DataFrame contents
readDf.show()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is from official documentaion on how to enable Vertica as data source in Spark-

> The Vertica Connector for Apache Spark is packaged as a JAR file. You install this file on your Spark cluster to enable Spark and Vertica to exchange data. In addition to the Connector JAR file, you also need the Vertica JDBC client library. The Connector uses this library to connect to the Vertica database.

> Both of these libraries are installed with the Vertica server and are available on all nodes in the Vertica cluster in the following locations:

> The Spark Connector files are located in /opt/vertica/packages/SparkConnector/lib.

> The JDBC client library is /opt/vertica/java/vertica-jdbc.jar.

Make sure Vertica JDBC jar is copied at the Spark library path.

[Getting the Spark Connector](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SparkConnector/GettingTheSparkConnector.htm?tocpath=Integrating%20with%20Apache%20Spark%7C_____1)

[Deploying the Vertica Connector for Apache Spark](https://www.vertica.com/docs/9.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SparkConnector/InstallationAndDeployment.htm?tocpath=Integrating%20with%20Apache%20Spark%7C_____2)